# Embedding IronPython in C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

I am just looking into using IronPython with C# and cannot seem to find any great documentation for what I need.  Basically I am trying to call methods from a .py file into a C# program.

I have the following which opens the module:

```
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
var test = ipy.UseFile("C:\\Users\\ktrg317\\Desktop\\Test.py");
```

But, I am unsure from here how to get access to the method inside there.  The example I have seen uses the dynamic keyword, however, at work I am only on C# 3.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [embedding](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/embedding.shtml) on the Voidspace site.

An example there, [*The IronPython Calculator and the Evaluator*](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dlr_hosting.shtml)
works over a simple python expression evaluator called from a `C#` program.

```
public string calculate(string input)
{
    try
    {
        ScriptSource source =
            engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(input,
                SourceCodeKind.Expression);

        object result = source.Execute(scope);
        return result.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try use the following code,

```
ScriptSource script;
script = eng.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(path);
CompiledCode code = script.Compile();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
code.Execute(scope);
```

<sup>It's from [this](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/hosting_api.shtml) article.</sup>

Or, if you prefer to invoke a method you can use something like this,

```
using (IronPython.Hosting.PythonEngine engine = new IronPython.Hosting.PythonEngine())
{
   engine.Execute(@"
   def foo(a, b):
   return a+b*2");

   // (1) Retrieve the function
   IronPython.Runtime.Calls.ICallable foo = (IronPython.Runtime.Calls.ICallable)engine.Evaluate("foo");

   // (2) Apply function
   object result = foo.Call(3, 25);
}
```

<sup>This example is from [here](http://www.redmountainsw.com/wordpress/archives/embedding-ironpython-c-calling-python-script).</sup>