# Need help invoking a function in IronPython from C#

Tags: c#, ironpython

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Instantiating a python class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579272/instantiating-a-python-class-in-c-sharp)
>   [Embedding IronPython in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978918/embedding-ironpython-in-c-sharp)

I trying this: [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx)

C#:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
    dynamic test = ipy.UseFile(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test.py");
    textBox1.Text = test.Simple();
}
```

Python:

```
def Simple():
    print "Hello from Python"
```

No error, when I run it, the textbox remain blank. What I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't know Python, but should not you return something from `Simple` function instead of just `print` ?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That is true, the link that he got the example from is printing to a console window. He should be using `return "Hello from Python"` instead.

Comment: yes guys you absolutely right... I though c# take the output of cmd and pass it to c#... Thanks for help

Comment: Converted my comment into answer. @KirkWoll, I don't think it is dup as the linked question is talking about how to actually do that, but not why particular method Python returns nothing.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, I guess you're right.  I was just thrown by the fact that when I tried to fix the spelling error in the OP's title, it wouldn't let me because of the existing question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Simple` function does not return anything, it just prints output to console with `print`. Something like `return "Hello from Python"` should give you results you want.

Side note: you may be able to intercept console output, but it would probably not what you are interested in.